# onclick event not adding class when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pNybA/) of my problem

HTML

```
<div onclick="toggleFolder()" title="on" class="folderImage"><img src="..." id=" /></div>
```

javascript:

```
function toggleFolder() {
    var toggle = $(this).attr('title');
    if( toggle == 'on' )
    {
        $(this).addClass("folderImageActive");
        $(this).attr('title','off');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).removeClass("folderImageActive");
        $(this).attr('title','on');
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the image, nothing happens. I was expecting it to add the class "folderImageActive" but it does not seem to do that.

Comment: You have jQuery: please don't use `onclick`, *use jQuery*.

Comment: Avoid posting titles which state a major library "doesn't work". It is vague and misleading and clearly `addClass` **does** work.

Comment: I edited your question so it fits the format here better. I understand that it can be hard when you first start at stackoverflow to correctly match the formatting. In the future, I think your questions will go over better if you can provide a reproducible demo, your code, and a little snippet of what you expected to happen but didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to pass the element you're clicking to the function as an argument :

```
<div onclick="toggleFolder($(this))" title="on" class="folderImage"><img src="..." id=" /></div>
```

And your function :

```
<script>
function toggleFolder($this) {
  //your code
}
</script>
```

Or, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Give your div an id or class:

```
<div class="image-class" title="on" class="folderImage"><img src="..." id=" /></div>
```

Then, using jQuery's `on`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".image-class", function () {
  var isOn= this.title === 'on';
  this.title= isOn ?  'off' : 'on';
  $(this).toggleClass("folderImageActive", isOn);
});
```

Comment: Wenn title='on' is set, it instantly works.
Wenn title='off' is set, first click nothing, second click, it works...
While I have extended the script with a function to save it to the database, it would be better when it works the first click (wenn title='off' is set).

Comment: @LinkinTED maybe put it in a fiddle? I don't get the problem

Comment: Here the fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uWcBJ/). On Fiddle, both work after two clicks...

Comment: @LinkinTED Change `$(this).toggleClass('folderImageActive', toggle == on);` to `$(this).toggleClass('folderImageActive');`

Comment: @Daedalus, thank you, that works. Also thanks to the others who helped with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your function, `this` refers to `window` not to the element, because you are calling the function "normally": `func()`. You have to set `this` explicitly

```
onclick="toggleFolder.call(this)"
```

or better yet, bind the event handler with jQuery:

```
$('div.folderImage').click(toggleFolder);
```

You can also simplify your function to:

```
function toggleFolder() {
    $(this).toggleClass('folderImageActive');
}
```

---

**Resources**:

- [quirksmode.org - Introduction to event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)
- [quirksmode.org - `this` in event handlers](http://quirksmode.org/js/this.html)
- [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [jQuery - Event basics](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/)

Comment: +1 - Although I do not like inline script, using `call` for the click event to pass `this` as the scope is a neat trick.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery for everything (almost) :

```
$('.folderImage').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('folderImageActive', this.title=='on');
    this.title = this.title == 'on' ? 'off' : 'on';
});
```